# Calling multiple Sub's with one line

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to call multiple Sub's with one line, at this moment I'm doing this (which's not practical)

```
' Textbox1
' Textbox2
' Textbox3
' Textbox...
' Textbox100

Private Sub TextBox1_AfterUpdate()

    Call TextBox1_Function

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_AfterUpdate()

    Call TextBox2_Function

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox3_AfterUpdate()

    Call TextBox3_Function

End Sub

' ......................... till Textbox100
```

I wonder now if I could something like this:

```
' Textbox1
' Textbox2
' Textbox3
' Textbox...
' Textbox100

Private Sub TextBox1_AfterUpdate()

    ' 1 - Get this Sub Object (I don't know if it's possible)
    ' 2 - Then Call the function 
    Call TextBox_Function OBJ_Name

End Sub

Function TextBox_Function(OBJ as Object)

    ' Do some code

End Function
```

Or anything better... With less line of code... Because I've 10 categories of text, each category have 100 textboxes each...

**It've to be different functions for some text boxes, because of that I can't use "For Each Textbox....."**

Comment: Should it be one function for **all** text boxes or different functions for **some** text boxes?

Comment: different functions for some text boxes

Comment: I can't see this working without the use of a class to handle the updates (or work around that).

Answer (score 2):

You can add event handlers for multiple text boxes by adding a class that handles the events. This class can include a `BoxType` so you can define for each `TextBox` which type it is, and in the event handler you can then distinguish the boxes by their `BoxType`.

1. Add a `Class Module` name it `clsTextBox` and paste the following code:

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Public WithEvents pTbx As MSForms.TextBox
   Public BoxType As String

   Private Sub pTbx_AfterUpdate()
       Select Case BoxType
           Case "TypeA"
               Debug.Print "Type A update " & pTbx.Name
           Case "TypeB"
               Debug.Print "Type B update " & pTbx.Name
       End Select
   End Sub

   Private Sub pTbx_Change()
       Select Case BoxType
           Case "TypeA"
               Debug.Print "Type A change " & pTbx.Name
           Case "TypeB"
               Debug.Print "Type B change " & pTbx.Name
       End Select
   End Sub
   ```

   Create the events you need.

   - `pTbx` refers to the text box that triggered the event.
   - `BoxType` specifies the type of the text box that triggered the event.
2. Initialize your text boxes. Therefore paste the following code in your user form

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Private mClsTbx() As clsTextBox

   Private Sub InitBoxes(ByVal BoxType As String, ByVal BoxNames As Variant)
       Dim StartIdx As Long

       On Error Resume Next
       StartIdx = UBound(mClsTbx) + 1
       On Error GoTo 0
       ReDim Preserve mClsTbx(StartIdx + UBound(BoxNames))

       Dim i As Long
       For i = 0 To UBound(BoxNames)
           Set mClsTbx(i + StartIdx) = New clsTextBox
           Set mClsTbx(i + StartIdx).pTbx = Controls(BoxNames(i))
           mClsTbx(i + StartIdx).BoxType = BoxType
       Next i
   End Sub


   Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
       'here we define which TextBox belongs to which type
       InitBoxes BoxType:="TypeA", BoxNames:=Array("TextBoxA1", "TextBoxA2")
       InitBoxes BoxType:="TypeB", BoxNames:=Array("TextBoxB1", "TextBoxB2")
       'add more types here
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: I'm getting compile error "Only Valid in object module" with this line:  Public ***WithEvents*** pTbx As MSForms.TextBox

Comment: @HeitorBadotti did you add a **class** module? A normal module doesn't work.

Comment: Yes! I added a Class module "Insert > Class Module"

Comment: Well, this works, I tested it. The first code block needs to be in the class module the second needs to be in your UserForm. Which Excel version are you using?

Comment: Yes, I did this... I'm using 1904 (Build 11601.20230)

Comment: Hm no idea, actually that's how I always do it and how it always worked for me. And in particular this code is tested and worked exactly like it is.